# Magento overriding

Tags: php, magento

I have edited addAttributeToFilter() in core file Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection and its working fine, but now when I wish to override this file in custom module (in order to escape core file changes), it does not work, anyone can give me the better idea.
I have tried both method to override this file 
1.
         catalog
                rewrite
                   resource_eav_mysql4_product_collection
                     Company_MODULE_Model_Producteav_Collection
                   resource_eav_mysql4_product_collection
                rewrite
            catalog

Comment: Your question is too abstract, you should provide more details and code samples.

Answer (score 0):

In magento there are three method for override the Core modules.
1- You will create same structure in your lcal folder like app/code/local/Mage/product...
2- You will create same structure in your namespace like app/code/namespace/module/file.
for this you should mentioned in config file which action you want override.

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <msa_web_catalog>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/admin/catalog_product]]></from>
                <to>/web/catalog_product</to>
        </msa_web_catalog>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

3-With help of event observer.